# Getting checkbox label

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementsbyclassname

Here I'm trying to get the names of the checked items. For example I want to get the Name **Milk** and display it.

Here it is the code:

```js
var ckboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("ckbox");
  for(i=0;i<ckboxes.length;i++){
  if(ckboxes[i].checked==true){
    values=ckboxes[i].value;
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="ckbox">Milk</label>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `values=ckboxes[i].parentElement.textContent;`

Comment: why did he get downvoted tho' ? Some explanation for the downvote might be a good idea, otherwise it's just meaningless..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the [next sibling node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)

```
ckboxes[i].nextSibling.nodeValue
```

**Demo**

```js
var ckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("ckbox");
for (i = 0; i < ckboxes.length; i++) {
  values = ckboxes[i].value;
  console.log(ckboxes[i].nextSibling.nodeValue);
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" class="ckbox">Milk</label>
```

However, if your code is going to have line-breaks within `label` and after `input`, then use @teemu's suggestion

```
ckboxes[i].parentElement.textContent;
```

Comment: @Teemu — `nextSibling` will be a text node

Comment: @Teemu Yes, I have shared the demo as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Milk` is not the part of `checkbox`. It is part of the `label`. Also you should not access `value` instead you should access `textContent`:

```js
var ckboxes=document.getElementsByClassName("ckbox");
for(i=0;i<ckboxes.length;i++){
  if(ckboxes[i].checked==true){
    var values=ckboxes[i].parentNode.textContent;
    console.log(values);
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="" checked class="ckbox">Milk</label>
```

Comment: @Teemu, updated the answer. Thanks for helping me to improve the answer.